# Highchart.js pass array doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm trying to use highchart.js.

here is my code

```
$.ajax({    type: "POST",
           url: "api/getListWeight",
           dataType: "json",
           data : {idBoxeur : idBoxeur} 

       }).done(function( dataWeightList ) {

           var data = [];

           $.each(dataWeightList, function( dataWeightList_index, dataWeightList_value ) {

              var splitDateRes = dataWeightList_value.weight_date.split("/");
              data.push("["+Date.UTC(splitDateRes[2],parseInt(splitDateRes[1], 10)-1,parseInt(splitDateRes[0], 10))+","+dataWeightList_value.weight_poids+"]");

           });

           var serie = data.join(",");

       }
```

Code snippet above result something like this :

```
[1330300800000,76.8],[1347235200000,78.8],[1347580800000,77.4]
```

just like expected.

Now chart

```
$('#graph').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'serie Name',
        data: [
                //pass serie from snippet above
                serie
        ]
    }]
});
```

Result : nothing happened..Chart is empty.

Only thing that i'm pretty sure, if i replace `serie` by `[1330300800000,76.8],[1347235200000,78.8],[1347580800000,77.4],[1348444800000,76.8]` inside my code, it work like a charm.

What i'm doing wrong ? How can i solve it ?

Thx for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing string while should be JS object.

That line:

```
data.push("["+Date.UTC(splitDateRes[2],parseInt(splitDateRes[1], 10)-1,parseInt(splitDateRes[0], 10))+","+dataWeightList_value.weight_poids+"]");
```

should be:

```
data.push([Date.UTC(splitDateRes[2],parseInt(splitDateRes[1], 10)-1,parseInt(splitDateRes[0], 10)),dataWeightList_value.weight_poids]);
```

And this line:

```
var serie = data.join(",");
```

what is for? Remove that line or at least remove that join, please.

Comment: Thx a lot !! Work perfectly. After modify got this error `Highcharts Error #14 : This happens if you pass in a string as a data point` fixed with adding parseFloat to data point.